# Create a network plan

Tags: networking

I am looking for a Software, that can scan a network and display me the IP addresses of the router and the switches.

The Network is pretty big.

I need it because everything is just plugged together anyhow and I want to bring structure into it. Before doing that I need to know the current configuration.

Starting from scratch would not be a possible solution, because it's a running System which is used 24/7

Free Tools are preferred but aint a must

Comment: On what OS do you want to be able to run the tool? Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing many tools,

**Lan State Pro** is the way to go,

since it creates you a network plan, which is **easy to understand** (the **Standard Network Icons** are used and gives you the possibility to add **custom Icons**)

---

### Advantages:

1. You are able to **modify** the plan after creation, within the tool.
2. You can **export** the plan to Visio and vice versa.
3. You can turn on **background scanning**, which is pretty good to
       detect new Clients in your network.
4. It supports **more than** the **most common network Protocolls**

### Disadvantages:

**Network Scan** is pretty slow.

---

Answer (score 0):

[Advanced IP Scanner](http://advanced-ip-scanner.com) would be good solution for you - free tool for learning about what is on your network, you can even save your scans to a spreadsheet which is very handy.

Comment: Please expand a little (maybe quote some of the product documentation) on why this would be a good tool. What does the tool offer?

Answer (score -1):

All the Tools you need are most probably integrated in every OS, but also somehow hidden. If it is a large Network, I guess there will be a DNS Server. And the DNS Server is probably the guy who can tell you everything about all the Network Devices Connected and registered.

You can use several tools to identify the machines. I personally prefer Mac and Linux regarding those operations.

Here is a good start for searching a tool for your request : 
http://alternativeto.net/software/angry-ip-scanner/?platform=mac

You should also have admin login codes to log into the machines and be sure what it is.